# JavaScript - gracefully handle unavailable functions

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to gracefully handle or intercept all function calls to an Object in JS? Basically in certain cases I want nothing to happen and I don't want JS to throw a "is not a function" exception. So not matter what function I call on the object, for example:

```
Obj.nonExistentFucntion1();
Obj.nonExistentFucntion2();
Obj.nonExistentFucntion3();
```

I want no errors to be thrown in the console.

Comment: Use `if (obj.nonExistentFucntion) obj.nonExistentFucntion()`?

Comment: If you don't want an `if`, you could use proxy to catch the non existing function.

Comment: How about making use of the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) which is capable of handling the call operator/`()` optionally as well ... `Obj?.nonExistentFucntion1?.();`